# Counting the instances of customers

Tags: sql, group-by

Say that I have a table with one column named CustomerId.
The example of the instance of this table is :

```
CustomerId
14
12
11
204
14
204
```

I want to write a query that counts the number of occurences of customer IDs.
At the end, I would like to have a result like this :

```
CustomerId      NumberOfOccurences
14              2
12              1
11              1
204             2
14              1
```

I cannot think of a way to do this.

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework... if it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: No, it is not. I am working on a project, right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the most basic example of GROUP BY

```
SELECT CustomerId, count(*) as NumberOfOccurences
    FROM tablex GROUP BY CustomerId;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Practice exercise #3](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php) on this page explains how to do this.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE customers
> (   customer_id     number(10)  not null,
>     customer_name   varchar2(50)    not null,
>     city    varchar2(50),   
>     CONSTRAINT customers_pk PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
> );
> ```

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7001, 'Microsoft', 'New York');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7002, 'IBM', 'Chicago');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7003, 'Red Hat', 'Detroit');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7004, 'Red Hat', 'New York');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7005, 'Red Hat', 'San Francisco');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7006, 'NVIDIA', 'New York');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7007, 'NVIDIA', 'LA');

INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, customer_name, city)
VALUES (7008, 'NVIDIA', 'LA');
```

Solution:

The following SQL statement would return the number of distinct cities for each customer_name in the customers table:

```
SELECT customer_name, COUNT(DISTINCT city) as "Distinct Cities"
FROM customers
GROUP BY customer_name;
```

It would return the following result set:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME   Distinct Cities
IBM     1
Microsoft   1
NVIDIA  2
Red Hat     3
```